# Why am I parsing this date time String incorrectly using Joda time in Java?

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

I'm trying to use Joda time to parse a String date time I get from an API response to a long (or Joda DateTime object) so I can store it in a database.

```
2018-01-13T16:45:33.416400+00:00
```

Right now what I have is:

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd?HH:mm:ss.??????+??:??");
```

The parts that have question marks in the pattern I am not sure what to put in. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think Joda supports microsecond precision. Other than that, you can use the default parser, e.g., `new DateTime("2018-01-13T16:45:33.416400+00:00")`. If you specifically need a `DateTimeFormatter`, you can use `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse( “2018-01-13T16:45:33.416400+00:00” )
```

## Microseconds

Your input string represents microseconds. Joda-Time is limited to milliseconds. So, square peg, round hole.

## java.time

Use the replacement for Joda-Time, the java.time classes.

### `OffsetDateTime`

The java.time classes such as `OffsetDateTime` have nanosecond resolution, for up to 9 digits of decimal fraction, more than enough for your microseconds.

Your String happens to comply with the ISO 8601 standard for date-time string formats. The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime  odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( “2018-01-13T16:45:33.416400+00:00” ) ;
```

### Database

With a driver supporting JDBC 4.2 or later, you can exchange java.time objects directly with your database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt.toInstant() ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).